Scala - Convert Map to Dataframe where Keys re the Column Titles
I wish to create a dataframe by using a map such that the keys of the map are the column titles, and the values of the map are the data itself. In python and pyspark, this can be done quite easily in numerous ways- typically with one line of code, even-, but in Scala, I'm having serious trouble.
Below is the equivalent in python of what I'm trying to accomplish in Scala:
#In Python:
Example_Map_aka_Dictionary = {"Key 1":["Value 1"],
                              "Key 2":[111111.1111],
                              "Key 3":[["Value_n"]]}
#Method 1:
import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(Example_Map_aka_Dictionary) 

#Method 2:
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps.DataFrame(Example_Map_aka_Dictionary)

#Method 3:
spark.createDataFrame(data=[[Value[0] for Value in Example_Map_aka_Dictionary.values()]], #Note the extra brackets []
                      schema=list(Example_Map_aka_Dictionary.keys()))

Note the extra brackets in Method 3. I think what could be happening is I'm unable to recreate this double-bracket effect in Scala.
According to Tutorial... Step 2: Create a DataFrame, the below code's format works, except I cannot figure out how to recreate Seq((...)) with that extra pair of parentheses:
//From https://docs.databricks.com/en/getting-started/dataframes.html#language-scala
val data = Seq((2021, "test", "Albany", "M", 42)) //notice the extra parentheses ().
val columns = Seq("Year", "First_Name", "County", "Sex", "Count")

val df1 = data.toDF(columns: _*)

In case there's something wrong with how I created the map itself, I've included how it was built below:
val Example_Data = Seq(("Big_Data_Value_1", 123.45, List("Big_Data_Value_n")))
val Example_Columns = Seq("Big_Data_Column_1", "Big_Data_Column_2", "Big_Data_Column_n")
val Example_df = Example_Data.toDF(Example_Columns: _*)

Example_df.show()

+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
|Big_Data_Column_1|Big_Data_Column_2| Big_Data_Column_n|
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Big_Data_Value_1|           123.45|[Big_Data_Value_n]|
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+

val Example_Map_after_Complicated_Operations = Example_df.columns
                                                         .map(Column_Title => Column_Title -> "Example String after If Statements. I'd like to script this as an org.apache.spark.sql.Column, but not even this string works")
                                                         .toMap

The way I see it, it would be more computationally efficient to build a dictionary and convert it into a dataframe than it would be to create a var df that's an empty copy of the Example_df and update it in a loop over and over with .withColumn. I know that in the most updated spark, there's the command withColumns which would probably be amazing, but 1. I want to learn how to convert a map into a dataframe because I'm sure I'll need to in the future if not now, 2. I literally can't acquire the latest Spark, because cluster configurations are completely out of my control (yes, it's a nightmare where I work, hence why I need to do whatever I can in Scala for the extra speed).
As you can see below, it's not so simple to recreate the .toDF
//Failed Formats 1-7:
val Values_format_1 = Example_Map_after_Complicated_Operations.values //error: value toDF is not a member of Iterable[String]
val Values_format_2 = Seq(Values_format_1)//error: value toDF is not a member of Iterable[String]
val Values_format_3 = List(Values_format_1) // error: value toDF is not a member of List[Iterable[String]]
val Values_format_4 =Values_format_1.toList//IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
val Values_format_5=List(Values_format_4) //IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
val Values_format_6=List((Values_format_1)) //error: value toDF is not a member of List[Iterable[String]]
val Values_format_7 = ((Values_format_1)).toList  //IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.


val Values_format_8 = (Values_format_1).toList
val Keys=Example_Map_after_Complicated_Operations.keys.toList

Values_format_8.toDF(Keys: _*)

IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (3): Big_Data_Column_1, Big_Data_Column_2, Big_Data_Column_n

I can't decipher this error message either. How does it think there are "old" and "new" column names, when brand new dataframe is being created? Where is the term "value" coming from?
Lastly, I've seen the following solution proposed all over the internet, but I fail to see its applicability, since it can only return the df in a 2-column format (and upon further research, it can't even be transposed, because it's so inefficient, even spark itself will try to stop you if there exists more than 1000 would-be columns):
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val m = Map("A"-> 0.11164610291904906, "B"-> 0.11856755943424617, "C" -> 0.1023171832681312)
val df = m.toSeq.toDF("name", "score")
df.show
+----+-------------------+
|name|              score|
+----+-------------------+
|   A|0.11164610291904906|
|   B|0.11856755943424617|
|   C| 0.1023171832681312|
+----+-------------------+


val data = Seq((2021, "test", "Albany", "M", 42)) //notice the extra parentheses ().
val df1 = data.toDF(columns: _*)


except I cannot figure out how to recreate Seq((...)) with that extra pair of parentheses:

The extra pair of parentheses is a tuple, any product will do here, so you could use a case class instead.

I can't decipher this error message either. How does it think there are "old" and "new" column names, when brand new dataframe is being created? Where is the term "value" coming from?

"value" is used as a placeholder for an anonymous single column value (your List[String]), then calling toDF you specify the three new column names.  The error is complaining because you have a single column you are trying to map to three columns.
wrt. withColumn usage, you are 100% correct, that's a really bad performance way to go. but I think it also doesn't solve your issue as withColumn(s) can only introduce columns based on an existing dataset.
Unfortunately you can't do exactly what you are after, but if you change the values in the map to also include the type (you could get that from another map of course) you can use the following:
// the types are String->Any, we need the actual type or a conversion to them
val exampleDataMap = Map("Big_Data_Column_1" -> ("Big_Data_Value_1", StringType),
  "Big_Data_Column_2" -> (123.45,DoubleType),
  "Big_Data_Column_n" -> Tuple2(List("Big_Data_Value_n"), org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType(StringType)))
val examplePairs = exampleDataMap.toSeq
  
// 'internal' api usage is required as lit() doesn't allow type to be provided
val columns = examplePairs.map( p => new Column(Literal.create(p._2._1, p._2._2)).as(p._1))
// we need to have a single row to select from so range(1) is used, id is then discarded by the select  
val exampleDF = sparkSession.range(1).select(columns: _*)
exampleDF.show

The internal api usage (Literal.create) may have a different version for your spark runtime.
edit: Based on further information provided in comments, this approach works for multiple rows with differing types:

val rowType = StructType(examplePairs.map( p => StructField(p._1, p._2._2)))
val rows = Seq(Row(exampleDataMap.map(_._2._1).toSeq: _*))

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
// using list
val exampleDFFromUtilList = sparkSession.createDataFrame(new java.util.ArrayList(rows.asJavaCollection), rowType)
exampleDFFromUtilList.show
// using RDD
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.makeRDD(rows)
val exampleDFFromRDD = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, rowType)
exampleDFFromRDD.show

in either case the StructType is required.  You cannot use RowEncoders to then leverage toDS.

As you predicted, the Literal.create is giving me issues. My online research hasn't helped for some reason; even finding an article on this is proving quite difficult. Do you have any recommendations- even for just reading?

Your ide should help with that, but also the other approach with Rows/createDataFrame should work without internal apis

val m = Map("A"-> 0.11164610291904906, "B"-> 0.11856755943424617, "C" -> 0.1023171832681312)
val columns = m.keys.toList
val vals = List(m.values.toList) // data is a list of lists
val df = vals.map(x =>(x(0), x(1), x(2))).toDF(columns: _*) // flatten the inner list
df.show()

Output:
List(List(0.11164610291904906, 0.11856755943424617, 0.1023171832681312))
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|                  A|                  B|                 C|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|0.11164610291904906|0.11856755943424617|0.1023171832681312|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+

import spark.implicits._
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(A -> 0.11164610291904906, B -> 0.11856755943424617, C -> 0.1023171832681312)
columns: List[String] = List(A, B, C)
vals: List[List[Double]] = List(List(0.11164610291904906, 0.11856755943424617, 0.1023171832681312))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double, B: double ... 1 more field]

Not sure how useful it is to have a dataframe with just a single row. A list of such maps is probably more real world usecase?
import spark.implicits._

val lm = List(
  Map("A"-> 0.11164610291904906, "B"-> 0.11856755943424617, "C" -> 0.1023171832681312),
  Map("A"-> 0.123, "B"-> 0.456, "C" -> 0.789)
)
val columns = lm(0).keys.toList  // assume all inner maps have same keys
val vals = lm.map(m => m.values.toList)
val df = vals.map(x =>(x(0), x(1), x(2))).toDF(columns: _*)
df.show()

Output:
List(List(0.11164610291904906, 0.11856755943424617, 0.1023171832681312), List(0.123, 0.456, 0.789))
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|                  A|                  B|                 C|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|0.11164610291904906|0.11856755943424617|0.1023171832681312|
|              0.123|              0.456|             0.789|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+

import spark.implicits._
lm: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]] = List(Map(A -> 0.11164610291904906, B -> 0.11856755943424617, C -> 0.1023171832681312), Map(A -> 0.123, B -> 0.456, C -> 0.789))
columns: List[String] = List(A, B, C)
vals: List[List[Double]] = List(List(0.11164610291904906, 0.11856755943424617, 0.1023171832681312), List(0.123, 0.456, 0.789))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double, B: double ... 1 more field]



How does it think there are "old" and "new" column names, when brand new dataframe is being created?

Values_format_8.toDF(Keys: _*)
Never worked with Scala, so not totally sure, but first guess would be that in your code you're missing the part where you flatten the inner lists.
So it's treating inner lists in Values_format_8 as a single column/values of array type, but then you give a list of length 3 as column names. Not matching the data (single column of array type).

Where is the term "value" coming from?
Seems like that's the default column name.

val m = Map("A"-> 0.11164610291904906, "B"-> 0.11856755943424617, "C" -> 0.1023171832681312)
val df = List(m.values.toList).toDF
df.show(20, false)

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[0.11164610291904906, 0.11856755943424617, 0.1023171832681312]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+


My actual use case is much longer than 1 row, you are correct. I made the examples 1 row to make the question easier to understand

I think your answer is so close, but I'm having an issue with the .map(x =>(x(0), x(1), x(2))) section, because when I change this to tuple comprehension (since in real life, I don't have 3 columns, I have n columns and can't just type them all out), what happens is I get a List(Vector(...)) instead of a List((...))  which is what you get. Maybe I'm doing tuple comprehension wrong?
Sticking with your syntax: .map(x =>(for (n<-0 to columns.size-1) yield x(n))) is what I'm using

@Sam can you please add the multiple rows to the question?  Also the example code above is focussing on a single type, but you also have other types in your question - please clarify what the types are.

@Chris
I think your request has made me realize that a df with more than one row can't be made with a single map whose values are lists and keys are the column titles. Apparently I would have to use Kashyap's method of using a list of maps that have identical keys to do so. Would you agree?
When I deliberately created one row for the question, I didn't realize how impossible it was to actually create more, and I think there's a lesson in this.

Kashyap's method doesn't work on arbitrary columns, the Row example in my solution does.  If you can provide your actual use case, rather than an abstract one, you may get a better example, but in all cases for multiple rows you still need column names and types and a sequence of data

@Sam, it'll depend on how generic you want the code to be. E.g. do you have 1000s of columns? Are column types different (in your example you have all doubles)? Are there any complex data types (instead of primitives like int, long, string, ...)? Update your question with info and we can point you in the right direction. If your number of columns are not too high, I would still recommend with hardcoding the tuple transformation .map(x =>(x(0), x(1), x(2))).

Column count is anywhere from 23 to 2008.
I'll provide better examples
